# Execute Phonegap function from Android Java

Tags: java, android, cordova

I'm developing an Android App with Phonegap 2.9.0 and I would like to implement a special function but I don't know how to do it.

I want to use an Android [Status Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) and if I execute a function in the Java Code, I want that Phonegap executes a special function.

But I don't find any method how to do this. I just found how to send data from Phonegap to the Java, but I'm looking for the other way around.

I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From inside your Activity extending CordovaActivity

```
this.appView.sendJavascript("window.mySpecialFunction()");
```

Or from inside a PhoneGap Plugin

```
this.webView.sendJavascript("window.mySpecialFunction()");
```

Obviously you would replace the string with whatever function you needed and you'd have to build any data needed into the js string as well.